# R Shiny how to get ggplot to do color/shapes by dplyr filters

Tags: r, input, ggplot2, shiny, aesthetics

the following code works(without any color/shape inputs), however trying to make the points different shapes/colors has proved difficult, I'm not sure what the problem is.

I'm trying to have:

year/range have a yellow outline around the shape

Product/inpt is to be different shapes

status/Role be different colors

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Membership Satisfaction"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Demographics Dashboard", tabName = "demos", icon = 
             icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

    tabItem(tabName = "demos",
          sidebarPanel(
            checkboxGroupInput("inpt","Select variables to plot", choices = 
                                 c("Web" = 1,"Huddle" = 3, "Other" = 5, 
            "Test" = 7)),
            checkboxGroupInput("role", 
                               "Select Primary Role of Interest", 
                               choices = c("Student" = 1, "Not" = 2)),
            checkboxGroupInput("range", 
                               "Select year(S) of Interest", 
                               choices = c("2016"=2,"July 2017"=1))),
          fluidPage(

            plotOutput("plot")
            #  tableOutput("test")

          )))))
```

My server:

```
server <- function(input,output){

  library(tidyverse)

   xPre <- reactive({
   inpt <- as.double(input$inpt)
   role <- as.double(input$role)
   range <- as.double(input$range)

   GapAnalysis_LongFormB %>%
  filter(Product %in% inpt,
         year %in% range)
  })


  yPre <- reactive({
  inpt <- as.double(input$inpt)+1
  role <- as.double(input$role)
  range <- as.double(input$range)

  GapAnalysis_LongFormB %>%
  filter(Product %in% inpt,
         year %in% range)
   })



  xPost<- reactive({
  xPre<- xPre()
  inpt <- as.double(input$inpt)
  role <- as.double(input$role)
  range <- as.double(input$range)

  xPre  %>%
  filter(year %in% range,
         Product %in% inpt,
         status %in% role)%>%
  group_by(Product, status,year)%>%
  summarize(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  pull(-1)

  })


yPost<- reactive({
yPre <- yPre()
inpt <- as.double(input$inpt)+1
role <- as.double(input$role)
range <- as.double(input$range)

yPre  %>%
  filter(year %in% range,
         Product %in% inpt,
         status %in% role)%>%
  group_by(Product, status,year)%>%
  summarize(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  pull(-1)


 })


ySum <- reactive({ 

yPre <- yPre()
inpt <- as.double(input$inpt)+1
role <- as.double(input$role)
range <- as.double(input$range)

yPre  %>%
  filter(year %in% range,
         Product %in% inpt)%>%
  group_by(Product,year)%>%
  summarize(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  pull(-1)
})



xSum <- reactive({ 
xPre <- xPre()
inpt <- as.double(input$inpt)
role <- as.double(input$role)
range <- as.double(input$range)

xPre  %>%
  filter(year %in% range,
         Product %in% inpt)%>%
  group_by(Product,year)%>%
  summarize(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  pull(-1)
})

xyCoords<- reactive({
xPost <- xPost()
yPost <- yPost()
xSum <- xSum()
ySum <- ySum()



as.data.frame(matrix(c(xPost,xSum,yPost,ySum),ncol = 2))


})



 output$test<- renderTable({
  xyCoords <- xyCoords()
 })

output$plot <- renderPlot({

  xyCoords <- xyCoords()    

  xyCoords %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=V1, y =V2 )) +
   geom_point(colour = "blue", shape = 17, size = 5 )+
   labs(x = "Mean Satisfaction", y = "Mean Importance") +
   xlim(0,5) + ylim(0,5) +
   geom_vline(xintercept=2.5) + 
   geom_hline(yintercept =  2.5)


 })

 }



shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

variable structure for GapAnalysis_LongFormB:

```
structure(list(status = c(1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5), year = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), Product = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), Score = c(2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4
)), .Names = c("status", "year", "Product", "Score"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

when I try doing color = input$inpt or shape = input$inpt I get an error "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): shape, colour, size"

Any ideas?? THANKS!!

Comment: I tried running your code with the data given, and when I change color to `input$inpt` it does not throw the error. This example is also a bit complicated, making it a little difficult to understand what you are trying to do and what isn't working. Can you produce a simpler example to show what you are trying to do? Perhaps also consider using a well known dataset like `iris` or `mtcars`.

Comment: @BrianStamper it throws the error when you try to add a role (student/not). I'll try to make a simpler version